# Is there a method like pd.to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know whether there is a method like pd.to_datetime, i.e. I want to have something like df['column1'].to_datetime()

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['column1'])` : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Just pass it as parameter, so `pd.to_datetime(df['mycolumn'])`.

Comment: I understand it. I just want to know, whether there is a method, not a function

Comment: as of now it is a high level pandas function and not a series attribute

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
raw_data = {'Player':      ['Matthew', 'John', 'Lisa', 'Taylor', 
                        'Matthew', 'John', 'Lisa', 'Taylor',
                        'Matthew', 'John', 'Lisa', 'Taylor',
                        'Matthew', 'John', 'Lisa', 'Taylor'],

        'Race Number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 
                        2, 2, 2, 2,
                        3, 3, 3, 3,
                        4, 4, 4, 4],

        'Place':       [2, 1, 3, 4,
                        3, 2, 4, 1,
                        1, 3, 4, 2,
                        2, 1, 3, 4],

       'Date of Race': ['1/1/2019','1/1/2019','1/1/2019','1/1/2019',
                        '1/2/2019','1/2/2019','1/2/2019','1/2/2019',
                        '1/3/2019','1/3/2019','1/3/2019','1/3/2019',
                        '1/4/2019','1/4/2019','1/4/2019','1/4/2019'            
       ]}

mariokartdata = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
mariokartdata.dtypes
```

This returns:

```
Player          object
Race Number      int64
Place            int64
Date of Race    object
```

But if you run:

```
mariokartdata['Date of Race'] = pd.to_datetime(mariokartdata['Date of Race'])
mariokartdata.dtypes
```

It will now return:

```
Player                  object
Race Number              int64
Place                    int64
Date of Race    datetime64[ns]
```

Thereby creating the datetime value for the column ['Date of Race'].